# Add line at file

Tags: sed, grep, cut

I have a file:

```
"struct_personnal": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mathieu"
    }
],
"struct_hospital": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "geo": "chamb",
        "nb": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "geo": "jsj",
        "nb": "SMITH"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "geo": "",
        "nb": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "geo": "marqui",
        "nb": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "geo": "oliwo",
        "nb": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "geo": "par",
        "nb": "5"
    }
]
```

I want to get number of the line of the last " } " for one block (struct_hospital, struct_personal, etc)
The file may contain other information.

If I want to add the text at the end of the block "struct_personnal", the output is:

```
"struct_personnal": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mathieu"
    }
   ##############
   #My text here#
   ##############
],
"struct_hospital": [
    {
        "id": "9",
        "geo": "chamb",
        "nb": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "geo": "jsj",
        "nb": "SMITH"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "geo": "",
        "nb": "12"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "geo": "marqui",
        "nb": "20"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "geo": "oliwo",
        "nb": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "geo": "par",
        "nb": "5"
    }
]
```

Same with struct_hospital

How to ? I don't understand ...
Thanks you !

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Your file looks like an json file, do you wanna implement a program to do it? And if yes, you could use a json object in this programming language. Otherwise you could count the brackets like a tree.

Comment: I have edit my message for output

Comment: is this a json file?\

Comment: @Crazy, in terms of JSON notation you can not add an arbitrary text in that way you've shown. What is the exact text to be added?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a json file then I would use python. Just load the file and convert the json contents to python dict using `json.load` function.

```
import json

content = None
with open('path/to/input_file') as f:
    content = json.load(f)

#change the key to struct_hospital if you want to append inside  struct_hospital block
content['struct_personnal'].append({'hi': 'my new text'})

with open('path/to/input_file', 'w') as w:
    json.dump(content, w)
```